# How can I open colorbox to specific image from another image?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, colorbox

I have this page here /products-page/rings/product-1-2/

as you can see there is 1 big image and 3 thumbnails

When you click on any of the small images, it will replace the big image.

Big Image code:

```
<a class="preview_link cboxElement" style="text-decoration:none;" href="/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/DSC_0118.jpg" rel="Teardrop Druzy Amethyst Ring">
<img id="product_image_736" class="product_image colorbox-736" width="400" src="/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/DSC_0118.jpg" title="Teardrop Druzy Amethyst Ring" alt="Teardrop Druzy Amethyst Ring">
<br>
<div style="text-align:center; color:#F39B91;">Click To Enlarge</div>
</a>
```

When you click on the big image jquery colorbox opens up, however in the colorbox it says I have 4 images when I only have 3, I guess my question is how do I get colorbox to ignore the big image, but still having the link to work....is that what I am looking for?

Thumbnails Code:

```
<div class="wpcart_gallery" style="text-align:center; padding-top:5px;">
<a class="thickbox cboxElement" title="DSC_0118" href="/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/DSC_0118.jpg" rel="Teardrop Druzy Amethyst Ring" rev="/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/DSC_0118.jpg">
<img class="attachment-gold-thumbnails colorbox-736" width="50" height="50" title="DSC_0118" alt="DSC_0118" src="/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/DSC_0118-50x50.jpg">
</a>
<a class="thickbox cboxElement" title="P7230376" href="/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/P7230376.jpg" rel="Teardrop Druzy Amethyst Ring" rev="/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/P7230376.jpg">
<img class="attachment-gold-thumbnails colorbox-736" width="50" height="50" title="P7230376" alt="P7230376" src="/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/P7230376-50x50.jpg">
</a>
<a class="thickbox cboxElement" title="P7230378" href="/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/P7230378.jpg" rel="Teardrop Druzy Amethyst Ring" rev="/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/P7230378.jpg">
<img class="attachment-gold-thumbnails colorbox-736" width="50" height="50" title="P7230378" alt="P7230378" src="/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/P7230378-50x50.jpg">
</a>
</div>
```

Everything is wrapped in `<div class="imagecol"> </div>`

Any help would be awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Jquery...this will work...

```
jQuery('document').ready(function($){
$(".wpcart_gallery a:first").removeClass("cboxElement");
jQuery(".wpcart_gallery img").click(function($){
jQuery(".wpcart_gallery a").addClass('cboxElement');
jQuery(this).closest('a').removeClass('cboxElement');
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember from using Colorbox, it only recognizes images, that have the `cboxElement`-class attached. Since you seem to already have a function, which changes the big image's source, how about removing the class `cboxElement` from the clicked thumbnail, and attaching it to the other two images? Might be worth giving it a try.

Comment: MartinCzerwi is correct. Simply remove the cboxElement class from the thumbnail that is being displayed in the large image.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend removing it in the large image, because you wouldn't be able to click the large picture, and activate the colorbox. Instead remove it in the thumbnail you clicked, means the thumbnail currently viewed in large mode doesn't have the class attached.

Comment: no me neither! I just didn't use the clearest way to describe what I meant. I was trying to say which ever image is in the large picture, remove the class from its equivalent thumbnail. (which is what you've said now too!)

Comment: I tried removing it from the large image and colorbox will not launch, I tried removing it from one of the thumbnails and it ignores it and if I remove from all thumbnails just the large image launches in colorbox

Answer (score 0):

You are getting 4 elements in the colorbox group - 3 thumbs + 1 main image - because your are telling colorbox to do so by giving all of them the `cboxElement` class.  That class is great when you need the default setup (e.g., a standard gallery of images with no external navigation).

However, you'll need to set up something less "default" for your situation.  I would recommend that you use your main image as the trigger for colorbox and set up your colorbox images in JS (without `cboxElement`).  The strategy goes like this:

1. Initialize all the thumb `img`'s into a colorbox group.
2. When clicking a thumb, the corresponding thumb `img`'s id is stored in the main image link
3. When clicking main image, open colorbox group, starting with the id stored

Here's the JS for that:

```
//STEP 1: initialize colorbox group
$(".attachment-gold-thumbnails").colorbox({
    rel: "myGroup"
    //other options...
});
```

Here we set up the colorbox group.  Note that we are using a class that gets the img of the thumbs, not the links you have around them. And strictly speaking, you don't need to use the class to pull them, just whatever is convenient for you.

```
//Each thumb updates main image 
$(".wpcart_gallery a").click(function() {
    var thumb_img_link = $(this),
        thumb_img = thumb_img_link.children().first(),
        product_image = $("#product_image_736"),
        product_image_link = product_image.parent();

    //STEP 2: update "data-thumb" attribute
    product_image_link.attr("data-thumb", "#" + thumb_img.attr("id"));

    product_image.attr({
        src: thumb_img.attr("href"),
        alt: thumb_img.attr("src"),
        title: thumb_img.attr("src")
    });

    return false;
});
```

This is the part you most likely want to customize.  At the very least, the thumb img id needs to be stored in the main image link.

```
//Main image opens colorbox
$(".preview_link").click(function() {
    var thumb_img_id = $(this).attr("data-thumb");

    //STEP 3
    $(thumb_img_id).colorbox({open:true});

    return false;
});
```

Using the id we stored in `data-thumb`, we open the colorbox group to that image.

You'll also need to make minor changes to the HTML:

```
<!-- Change 1: add data-thumb -->
<a class="preview_link" data-thumb="#thumb1" ...>
    ...
</a>

<div class="wpcart_gallery">
    <a class="thickbox" ... >
        <!-- 
        Change 2: Give the img an id so we can reference it
        Change 3: Instead of the "rev" attribute, colorbox will 
        read the "href" attribute in the img tag -->
        <img id="thumb1" href="http://images.picturesdepot.com/photo/s/scenery_wallpaper,_wallpaper-209423.jpg" ... >
    </a>
</div>
```

Check out the jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/DonamiteIsTNT/E6VyT/1/)

Comment: I tried your code and all that happens it that colour box will open, however no images load up :(

Comment: Sounds like something is missing.  Fortunately I did provide a working example in the jsfiddle provided (at the end of the answer).  There you can find the complete code needed to open the colorbox to the specific image as well as see it running.